# Submenu of sidebar is not opening on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please check the codes and let me know , where i made the mistake that submenu of sidebar is not opening on click. Working code to my link is attached.https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/yLjWwGQ. I tried to do but couldn't, I shall be highly obliged if you can help me in creating submenu of services which is initially kept hidden and i want to display on click by event listener method.

```js
//for sidebar
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
//for sidebar

//for sidebar submenu
const caretButton = document.querySelectorAll(".caret");

caretButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("show");
  })
);
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
}
header{
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background: coral;
  position:fixed;
}
header img{
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float:right;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: grab;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(45deg);
}

#mySidebar{
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
  transform:translateX(-250px);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:calc(100vh - 50px); 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top:50px;
}
/* then a few properties removed and box-sizing added */
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-nav {
  flex:1 ;
  overflow:auto;
}
#mySidebar.open{
  transform:translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-header{
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  height: 3rem;
}
.sidebar-header .profile{
  display:  flex;
  color: #fff;
}
.profile .profile-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left:  20px;
}
.profile .profile-name{
  display: inline-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.profile .profile-name i{
  margin: -2px 5px 0 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.profile-stats{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap:  0.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.profile-stats .stats{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#followerCount, #mediaCount,#followingCount{
  font-size: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav{
margin:  0;
overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#007bff;
    padding:  5px 10px;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .active,
.sidebar-nav ul .active a .icon{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li:hover,
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a .icon, 
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .icon{
  color:#007bff;
  width:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .caret{
  left: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar-nav .sidebar-nav-header{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: -0.75rem 1.5rem;
  color:#0c7db1;
}
.sidebar-footer{
  background: #FF7F50;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar-footer span a{
  display: block;
  padding:.5em 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #FF7F50;
  font-weight:  600 !important;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-footer span i{
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sub-menu{
  display:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sub-menu.show{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css">
<header>
        <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        <div id="sidebar-toggle">
            <div class="bar4"></div>
            <div class="bar5"></div>
            <div class="bar6"></div>
        </div> 
    </header>
<div class="sidebar" id="mySidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHMnA03XDdf3w/company-logo_200_200/0/1519855918965?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=J3kUMZwIphc90TFKH5oOO9Sa9K59fimgJf-s_okU3zs">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-name">
                <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i><span>Umann Goswami</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--sidebar-header-->
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></span>Services<span class="caret fas fa-angle-down"</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i></span>Connect</a>
             </li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></span>Home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></span>home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
           Admin
        </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></span>home</a></li>

            </ul>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
            Profile
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas
             fa-user"></i></span>home</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
            Analysis
        </div>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--sidebar-nav-->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <span><a href=""><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>Logout</span></a>
    </div>
</div><!--sidebar-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//for sidebar
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
//for sidebar

//for sidebar submenu
const caretButton = document.querySelectorAll(".caret");

caretButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("show");
  })
);
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
}
header{
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  background: coral;
  position:fixed;
}
header img{
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  float:right;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: grab;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(45deg);
}

#mySidebar{
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
  transform:translateX(-250px);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:calc(100vh - 50px); 
  box-sizing:border-box;
  top:50px;
}
/* then a few properties removed and box-sizing added */
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-nav {
  flex:1 ;
  overflow:auto;
}
#mySidebar.open{
  transform:translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-header{
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  height: 3rem;
}
.sidebar-header .profile{
  display:  flex;
  color: #fff;
}
.profile .profile-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left:  20px;
}
.profile .profile-name{
  display: inline-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.profile .profile-name i{
  margin: -2px 5px 0 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.profile-stats{
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap:  0.25rem;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.profile-stats .stats{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#followerCount, #mediaCount,#followingCount{
  font-size: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav{
margin:  0;
overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:#007bff;
    padding:  5px 10px;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .active,
.sidebar-nav ul .active a .icon{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li:hover,
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a .icon, 
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover a{
    background:#007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .icon{
  color:#007bff;
  width:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a .caret{
  left: 90px;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar-nav .sidebar-nav-header{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: -0.75rem 1.5rem;
  color:#0c7db1;
}
.sidebar-footer{
  background: #FF7F50;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar-footer span a{
  display: block;
  padding:.5em 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #FF7F50;
  font-weight:  600 !important;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-footer span i{
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sub-menu{
  display:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sub-menu.show{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css">
<header>
        <img src="https://www.tailorbrands.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/mcdonalds-logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Logo">
        <div id="sidebar-toggle">
            <div class="bar4"></div>
            <div class="bar5"></div>
            <div class="bar6"></div>
        </div> 
    </header>
<div class="sidebar" id="mySidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHMnA03XDdf3w/company-logo_200_200/0/1519855918965?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=J3kUMZwIphc90TFKH5oOO9Sa9K59fimgJf-s_okU3zs">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-name">
                <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i><span>Umann Goswami</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--sidebar-header-->
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li class='caret'><a><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></span>Services<span class="caret fas fa-angle-down"</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i></span>Connect</a>
             </li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i></span>Home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></span>home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span>home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
           Admin
        </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></span>home</a></li>

            </ul>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
            Profile
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas
             fa-user"></i></span>home</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="sidebar-nav-header">
            Analysis
        </div>
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--sidebar-nav-->
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
        <span><a href=""><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>Logout</span></a>
    </div>
</div><!--sidebar-->
```

add to your li `class='caret'`

Comment: It won't work properly, because the target's parent won't be the `li` unless you click the `a` element. It will throw an error or if there are more submenus it will open/close the first one in the `ul`

Comment: Codes didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the parent `li` element

```
<li class="withsub">
    <a>
       <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i></span>
       Services<span class="caret fas fa-angle-down"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

in the js get the `li` elements, then in the loop get the `.sub-menu` child element

```
const withSubButton = document.querySelectorAll(".withsub");

withSubButton.forEach((el) =>
   el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   const subMenu = el.querySelector(".sub-menu");

    subMenu.classList.toggle("show");
  });
);
```